# Animating elements on page scroll

Tags: jquery, animation, scroll

Well I'm not sure whether I have given a suitable heading. Actually I want an effect similar to the one in [this](https://victoriabeckham.landrover.com/INT).

Can someone please suggest me a  library/plugin to achieve the same or anything that will help me to get start with? Even that would be of great help! Obviously, I'm not asking for the direct code, just right direction to go ahead.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this will help you :

http://johnpolacek.github.com/scrollorama/

http://f6design.com/journal/2011/08/06/build-a-parallax-scrolling-website-interface-with-jquery-and-css/

Comment: thanx :) but it(1) doesn't seem to be that smooth as the one in the link in ques

Comment: also I need horizantal animation too